# jquery validation error message - change the location of message

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I am using jquery validation plugin.
I have an html that looks like:

```
<h2>Select A City</h2>

<select class="required city-selection-list" id="city_city_id" name="city[city_id]">
  <option value=""></option>

  <option value="146">San Francisco Bay Area</option>
  <option value="147">San Francisco</option>
  <option value="311">Los Angeles</option>
  <option value="344">New York</option>
  <option value="395">San Diego</option>
 </select>
```

The error message is currently displaying *after* the select box.
This causes my page to shift left and messes up how it looks.

How do I display it after *Select A City* instead of inlining it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change you selectors and placement, but this should give you an idea on how it works.

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.hasClass("city-selection-list")) {
           error.insertBefore(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this override the default validation? I added your piece of code to jquery.validation.js and it complains that .validate-form is not a function. //  `http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/setDefaults
 setDefaults: function(settings) {
  $.extend( $.validator.defaults, settings );
        errorPlacement: function(errorClass, element) {
        if (element.hasClass("city-selection-list")) {
           errorClass.insertBefore(element);
        }
    }
 }`

Comment: Kind of, it sets the default. However you can, as I did, apply logic to only effect certain elements. Here is the official doc's page on this, look at the source. http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/custom-methods-demo.html

Comment: you can set rules to specific form without overriding the default ones : 
`$('#form_name').validate({
   errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
       // some code 
        
    }
      });`

Comment: What if you only want to do it for one input on the form?

Comment: Easiest way in the above method would just be add a unique CSS class name and target that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a container div below h2

```
<div id='errorContainer'></div>
```

add **errorPlacement:** line with your validate code and it will display all errors inside errorCotainer div

```
$( "#frm_register" ).validate(
{

//  errorElement: "span",// by default em is used to display each error message

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo( $('#errorContainer'));
    }

});
```